# How can we connect databricks to SQL database using service principal with python?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-databricks

From Azure Databricks I would like to insert some dataframes as tables in a sql database. How can I do to connect Azure Databricks with Azure SQL Database using service principal with python ?

I searched something similar with:

```
jdbcHostname = "..."
jdbcDatabase = "..."
jdbcPort = ...
jdbcUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://{0}:{1};database={2}".format(jdbcHostname, jdbcPort, jdbcDatabase)

connectionProperties = {
  "user" : "...",
  "password" : "...",
  "driver" : "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
}
```

But found nothing to do with Python. How can I do it ? Maybe with pyspark like below ?

```
hostname = "<servername>.database.windows.net"
server_name = "jdbc:sqlserver://{0}".format(hostname)

database_name = "<databasename>"
url = server_name + ";" + "databaseName=" + database_name + ";"
print(url)

table_name = "<tablename>"
username = "<username>"
password = dbutils.secrets.get(scope='', key='passwordScopeName')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To connect to ***Azure SQL Database***, you will need to install the [SQL Spark Connector](https://github.com/microsoft/sql-spark-connector) and the [Microsoft Azure Active Directory Authentication Library  for Python](https://pypi.org/project/adal/).

Go to your cluster in Databricks and Install
***com.microsoft.azure:spark-mssql-connector_2.12_3.0:1.0.0-alpha from Maven*** And ***adal*** from ***PyPI***.
Make sure both the client Id and secret to Key Vault are assigned

> **Azure SQL**

The app needs ***permission to login*** into ***Azure SQL*** to access the object. ***Create service principle*** to object then grant it permissions on the underlying objects, In the example below I have given the service principal select permission on the dbo schema. ***The code samples are at the Reference**.*

[image: Ref1]

**We will also create a table in the database**

[image: Ref1]

> **Azure SQL Snippet:**

[image: Ref3]

[image: Ref4]

**Reference:**

https://www.thedataswamp.com/blog/databricks-connect-to-azure-sql-with-service-principal

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/spark/connector?view=sql-server-ver15